# Cannot change value of variable in groovy soapui

Tags: variables, groovy

```
def activeEnvironment = "a"
activeEnviornment="b"
log.info("active environment = $activeEnvironment")
```

When I run the code above, on the log it shows active environemnt = a. Why doesnt it show b?

Answer (score 0):

Your spelling of `environment` is wrong in your second assignment, so you've created a new variable

Change

```
activeEnviornment="b"
```

To

```
activeEnvironment="b"
```